# Can't import matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module, project

It shows this when I import `matplotlib`

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt
```

Error code:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

I need  to make a project which involve  using  `matplotlib`.

Comment: Did you install `matplotlib`? You can use `pip` to do so `pip install matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't installed the library 'matplotlib'.

Go to command prompt and enter:

```
python -V
```

If a python version text is shown, then enter the following:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Note: If you're using kaggle notebook or google collab then use the below code to run in a cell:

```
!pip install matplotlib
```